# How to find unique words in each row of a two dimension matrix in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, row, unique, words

I have a two dimension huge matrix (A). Each cell of this matrix is either empty or contains a word. I want to find the unique words in each row of this matrix separately and store them in another two dimension matrix (B) such that the Kth row of B contains the unique elements of the Kth row in A. I tried this way but it said that the input must be a cell array:

```
 % engine

 B = sort(A,2) ;

 d = [true(1,size(B,2)) ; diff(B)>0] ;

 B = mat2cell(B(d).',1,sum(d));

 % check if B{K} contains the unique elements of the Kth row of A

 for i=1:size(A,1),

     tf(i) = isequal(B{i},unique(A(i,:))) ;
 end

 all(tf)
```

I would appreciate your help to solve this error.

Comment: I'm confused.  You said that each row either contains a word or is empty, yet your description further on and your title suggest that there is **more than one word** per row.  Can you please clarify the following: (1) What is `A`? Is this a cell array? (2) If `A` is a cell array, is each element a word? (3) Is each row of this cell array a sentence?

Comment: Sure, here is the clarification: 1) A is the two dimension matrix that I have as the input. I said each cell of the matrix is either empty or includes a word, not each row. 2) Each cell will include a word, if it  is not empty. 3) No, each row of the matrix is not a sentence.

Comment: OK, so `A` is a 2D cell matrix then? 2D matrix can mean anything... doubles, structs, cells, etc.  Also, can you post an example of some data you have, so when I answer your question, you can see whether or not I am answering your question properly?

Comment: Never mind, I have an answer for you.  Give me one moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You almost have it correct.  If I understand your question correctly, you want to iterate over each row of your matrix, find unique words, and create a new row of cells in an output cell array that contain these words.  Here is an example using a 3 x 5 matrix of cell elements:

```
A = 'Hi hi hi how are you my my name is Ray Ray Ray StackOverflow StackOverflow';
Acell = reshape(strsplit(A, ' '), 3, 5).'; % // Use for MATLAB R2013a and up
%//Acell = reshape(regexp(A, ' ', 'split'), 3, 5).'; %// Use for MATLAB R2012b and below
```

Here is what `Acell` looks like:

```
Acell = 

'Hi'     'hi'               'hi'           
'how'    'are'              'you'          
'my'     'my'               'name'         
'is'     'Ray'              'Ray'          
'Ray'    'StackOverflow'    'StackOverflow'
```

Now, let's insert some blank strings in the cell array to mimic your situation

```
Acell{1,1} = '';
Acell{4,1} = '';
```

Therefore:

```
Acell = 

''       'hi'               'hi'           
'how'    'are'              'you'          
'my'     'my'               'name'         
''       'Ray'              'Ray'          
'Ray'    'StackOverflow'    'StackOverflow'
```

Now, let's initialize the matrix `B` as a cell array that will store this output:

```
B = cell(size(Acell), 1);
```

This will have as many rows  as `Acell` will have.  However, what will happen is that each row of `B` will be **uneven**.  As such, the only way that we can accomplish what you want down is that each element of `B` will also be a **cell** array.  MATLAB does not support creating matrices that have unequal columns per row.  Now, we can simply loop through each row of `A`, run `unique`, then assign this to each row of `B`:

```
for idx = 1 : size(Acell, 1)
    B{idx} = unique(Acell(idx,:));
end
```

Now let's see `B`:

```
B = 

{1x2 cell}
{1x3 cell}
{1x2 cell}
{1x2 cell}
{1x2 cell}
```

Let's see each `cell` by themselves:

```
for idx = 1 : numel(B)
    disp(B{idx});
end
```

We thus get:

```
''    'hi'

'are'    'how'    'you'

'my'    'name'

''    'Ray'

'Ray'    'StackOverflow'
```

You'll notice that the words are also sorted in alphabetical order.  That's how `unique` orders things.  Also note that `unique` does not differentiate between upper case and lower case letters.  As such, `Hi` and `hi` would count as different words.  If this is not your desired behaviour and you want to filter out words where the case should not matter, convert all of the letters to lower case by using the [`lower`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/lower.html) function before doing any processing.  You can convert all of your strings to lower by using `cellfun`

```
Alower = cellfun(@lower, A, 'UniformOutput', false);
```

If you compare `B` with `Acell`, this gives you the unique words per row.

Comment: @user3439050 You're welcome.  If this answer has helped you, please consider accepting it.  Click on the checkmark icon at the top of my post towards the left, below the up and down vote buttons.